# Query on indexed table too slow in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table with 46230 rows(1 doc, 4623 sentences and 10 chunks for each sentence):

```
create table chunks(
doc varchar,
sentenceid int,
chunkid int,
chunk bit(10)
);
```

With the query I want to compare sentence chunks with other sentence chunks that have same chunkid:

```
SELECT
       a.sentenceid,
       b.sentenceid, a.chunkid,
       Length(Replace(Cast(a.chunk & b.chunk AS TEXT), '0', ''))::float / Length(a.chunk)::float
FROM  chunks2 a
INNER JOIN chunks2 b
        ON a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid and  a.chunkid = b.chunkid;
```

I ran explain analyze on unindexed table, composite index and both indexed separately:

No index:

```
Hash Join  (cost=1335.17..4549476.28 rows=71249559 width=26) (actual time=140.532..1160629.611 rows=106837530 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.chunkid = b.chunkid)
   Join Filter: (a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 106883760
   ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 a  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.043..76.936 rows=46230 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=757.30..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=140.056..140.056 rows=46230 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2680kB
         ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 b  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.032..65.781 rows=46230 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.518 ms
 Execution time: 1217920.271 ms
```

Index(sentenceid) & index(chunkind):

```
Hash Join  (cost=1335.17..4549476.28 rows=71249559 width=26) (actual time=143.719..1155138.691 rows=106837530 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.chunkid = b.chunkid)
   Join Filter: (a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 106883760
   ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 a  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.038..74.031 rows=46230 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=757.30..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=142.160..142.160 rows=46230 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2680kB
         ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 b  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.031..63.628 rows=46230 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.664 ms
 Execution time: 1213844.696 ms
```

Index(sentenceid, chunkid):

```
Hash Join  (cost=1335.17..4549476.28 rows=71249559 width=26) (actual time=144.376..1156178.110 rows=106837530 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.chunkid = b.chunkid)
   Join Filter: (a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 106883760
   ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 a  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.039..77.275 rows=46230 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=757.30..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=142.954..142.954 rows=46230 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2680kB
         ->  Seq Scan on chunks2 b  (cost=0.00..757.30 rows=46230 width=15) (actual time=0.031..64.340 rows=46230 loops=1)
 Planning time: 1.209 ms
 Execution time: 1212779.012 ms
```

I know they have the same operations and no index was used. Where is my mistake and how to speed up query with index? Or how to use indexes efficiently in my case?

Comment: what is the purpose of this condition: `a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid`?

Comment: when comparing sentences: 1 compared to 2, 1 to 3, the same result will be for 3 compared to 1 or 2 compared to 1. to decrease number of comparisons `a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid` is used

Comment: You could try a composite index that also includes the `chunk` (`chunkid`, `sentenceid`, `chunk`), but I don't think that PostgreSQL supports index-only retrieval, so I doubt that would help.

Comment: @TomH The data I wrote here is just for testing. In reality I have at least 250 chunks with size of 40 characters each. Putting them in index can be heavy.

Comment: why you mean by `(1 doc, 4623 sentences and 10 chunks for each sentence):` ?? Also if you have a bigger table just put something on the question to indicate that. Isnt clear to me what is `250 chunks size 40`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I meant I have 1 distinct value for doc column, 4623 for sentenceid column and 10 distinct values for chunkid column. `doc 1 1, doc 1 2, doc 1 3, ..... doc 2 1, doc 2 2,...., doc 3 1...doc 4623 10`

Comment: Database development is full of tradeoffs. You can spend time or you can spend resources.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to do some kind of document similarity, maybe plagiarism detection, but are trying to compare everything to everything. Obviously, this will take a lot of time.

Comment: @hruske 4623 sentence formatted to bag of words(10,000 most common words) representation and then compared takes about 9.5 hours. According to more experience people whom I know, this is a very slow process and needs to be reduced drastically.

Comment: There is reason to think using the index you propose would be an improvement.  You are joining most of the table to itself.  Hash joins are an efficient way to do this and indexes are not.  What speed do you get if you leave the dynamic calculation out of the select list?

Comment: @jjanes I do not know how to leave the dynamic calculation out of the select list. Maybe any hint how to do it?

Comment: @Masyaf Does your friend use postgres or any other relational database to do this? Because I don't think that's a common usage pattern for relational DB. Also, is there a way to limit how similar should the rows be?

Comment: @hruske I know it is more Natural Language Processing stuff. No, I don't think I can limit it even more.

Comment: To remove the dynamic calculation, delete the line beginning with "Length", and delete the comma from the end of the prior line.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include verbatim create index statements, they would be very helpful.

First thing: The general rule is to [index for equality first, then for ranges.](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates)

So if you are querying for chunkid equal and sentenceid less, then you should create index as:

```
create index chunks2_chunkid_idx on chunks2 (chunkid, sentenceid);
```

Second: You are joining whole table with itself. This will never be a cheap operation, and postgres figures this out and skips index use altogether. Index would be of use if your query only touched a small subset of table.

I'm guessing you are trying to find similar sentences, but I think you are approaching this not the best way.

Comment: Actually I did. I wrote `I ran explain analyze on unindexed table, composite index and both indexed separately`. I did `create index chunks2_idx on chunks2 (chunkid, sentenceid)` and also `(sentenceid, chunkid)` and on both of them separately. But the time for (chunkid, sentenceid) was worse than for (sentenecid, chunkid)